# The procedure entry point _ZSt28__ throw_bad_array_new_lengthv could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWyB2.png)

I got this error after compiling my C++ project and trying to run the .exe file in cmd prompt.
For some reason this works fine and the file executes normally on my laptop, but on my desktop I get this error.

I am using g++ compiler and gdb debugger on both devices.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that there is a difference in the DLL versions installed on the two machines and one contains that function and the other does not.